# How do I prevent stuttering in a Tkinter GUI with an Animated plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-animation

Here is the code, which shows an animated plot and a GUI to display the value:

```
import random
import time
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import threading


root = tk.Tk()
gui_text = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=gui_text).pack()
x = []
y = []


def data_thread():
    while True:
        random_value = random.random()
        x.append(len(x))
        y.append(random_value)
        gui_text.set(f"Random Value: {random_value:.2f}")
        time.sleep(0.09)


def init():
    plot_data.set_data([], [])
    return (plot_data,)


def animate(frame):
    plot_data.set_data(x, y)
    plot_axes.relim()
    plot_axes.autoscale_view(True)
    return (plot_data,)


plot_figure = plt.figure()
plot_axes = plt.axes()
(plot_data,) = plot_axes.plot([], [])

animation = animation.FuncAnimation(plot_figure, animate, init_func=init, interval=1000, blit=False)
plt.show(block=False)

thread = threading.Thread(target=data_thread)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

As you can see when the plot is updating/animating (every second) the gui stops updating the value (displayed as "Random Value:")
Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method) help ?

Comment: @rochard4u No, same issue. Updating the Plot seems to cause everything else to momentarily pause... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

First, **never** use thread with Tkinter (or use it really carefully), you should use only 1 loop (mainloop). This is because tkinter will create memory leaks when you use threading.

Secondly, the animate instance is pretty complicated to use. You can do the same thing by clearing values and plot again with new values (cf. code below).

Finally, if you use my code (it works) but you plot values really quickly, I suggest you to limit plotted numbers (I can help you if you need with this).

Here my code will get a random value every 0.01 secs and plot it directly. I commented my code so it's more clear.

Feel free to ask me any question ! Have a nice day.

```
import random 
import tkinter as tk 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args):        
        super().__init__() 

        #var
        self.x_list = [] #list of x position | they need to be the same size
        self.y_list = [] #list of y position
        self.nbrOfPoints = 0 

        #widget creation
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self) #label displaying random values

        self.figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(7,3), dpi=100) #figure that will hold your plot
        self.subplot = self.figure.add_subplot(111) #plot holded by figure

        self.GraphCanva = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self) #canvas from figure
        self.GraphCanva.get_tk_widget().pack() #place your canvas

        #widget placement
        self.label1.pack()

        self.update_values_to_plot() #launch the loop to updates values to plot
        self.update_plot() #lauch loop that will update the plot

    def update_values_to_plot(self) :
        random_value = self.randomValue() #get a random value between 0.0 and 1.0
        self.x_list.append(random_value) #add the random valut to x list
        self.y_list.append(self.nbrOfPoints) #add 0, 1, 2 ... to y list
        self.nbrOfPoints += 1

        #label is a disctionnary so you can update values like this
        self.label1['text'] = "Random value : " + str(random_value) #show random value on label

        self.after(10, self.update_values_to_plot) #call back this function every 0.5 secs

    def randomValue(self) :
        return random.random() #return a random value
    
    def update_plot(self) : #update the plot
        self.subplot.cla() #clear plot
        self.subplot.plot(self.y_list, self.x_list, '-o', label="Random values", color='blue') #place new values 

        self.GraphCanva.draw_idle() #draw what's in your canva (your plot)
        self.after(10, self.update_plot) #call back function every 0.5secs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    second_window = Window()
    second_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I'm aware tkinter `stringvar.set()` is thread safe or at least it doesn't cause any major issues. In the end I just changed/reduced the update rate for the GUI so that it looks like there is no pause